# 「GROUP_CONCAT」を2カラムに対して指定すると、思うような取得結果が取れない。結合の仕方がおかしい？

Tags: mysql, sql

**前提**
mainテーブル
・idカラムの値が9のレコード1件(常に1件)

tableaテーブル
・m_idカラムの値が9のレコード5件(idカラムの値によって変動)

tablebテーブル
・m_idカラムの値が9のレコード1件(idカラムの値によって変動)

---

**この時、｢mainテーブル.idカラム」と「tableaテーブルm_idカラム」と「tablebテーブルm_idカラム」を結合してデータ取得したい**
取得したい内容(idカラムの値は9)
・mainテーブル全カラム
・tableaテーブルcolaカラム5件分を連結した内容
・tablebテーブルcolbカラム1件分(を連結した内容)

---

**うまくいかないSQL**
・colbconcatの連結数がcolaconcatと同じになってしまう

```
SELECT 
  m.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(a.cola) AS colaconcat,
  GROUP_CONCAT(b.colb) AS colbconcat,
FROM main AS m
  LEFT JOIN tablea AS a ON (m.id = a.m_id)
  LEFT JOIN tableb AS b ON (m.id = b.m_id)
WHERE m.id = 9
GROUP BY m.id
```

下記のような内容を期待しているけど
★,☆,■,□,●
▲

実際に取得される内容は
★,☆,■,□,●
▲,▲,▲,▲,▲

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`group_concat()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) 関数は各行の値を連結するわけですが、質問に書かれたSQLの場合、連結前はどのような表になっているでしょうか。

```
SELECT 
  id, cola, colb
FROM main AS m
  LEFT JOIN tablea AS a ON (m.id = a.m_id)
  LEFT JOIN tableb AS b ON (m.id = b.m_id)
WHERE m.id = 9
```

mainの行に対してtableaとtablebを同時にJOINしているので・・・

```
9,1,1
9,2,1
9,3,1
9,4,1
9,5,1
```

`group_concat(colb)` とすると、`1,1,1,1,1` になるわけです。

期待通りの結果を得るには、JOINする前に `group_concat()` する必要があります。

```
SELECT 
  m.*, a.colaconcat, b.colbconcat
FROM main AS m
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT m_id, group_concat(cola) AS colaconcat FROM tablea
  ) AS a ON (m.id = a.m_id)
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT m_id, group_concat(colb) AS colbconcat FROM tableb
  ) AS b ON (m.id = b.m_id)
WHERE m.id = 9;
```

こうなるとサブクエリの方がわかりやすいかもしれません（パフォーマンスは知りませんが）。

```
SELECT 
  m.*,
  (SELECT group_concat(cola) FROM tablea WHERE m_id = m.id) AS colaconcat,
  (SELECT group_concat(colb) FROM tableb WHERE m_id = m.id) AS colbconcat
FROM main AS m
WHERE m.id = 9;
```

JOINでは各テーブルの対応する行全ての組み合わせが結果に表れます。今回はtableb側が1行だったのでたまたまtableaの行数と一致しましたが、tablebが複数行だったらもっと増えていたことでしょう。